# How to execute func present in a ViewController from another?

Tags: swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am a beginner in Swift, and I do not yet understand all the elements.

I am trying to execute a function present in a ViewController (ProjectTabBarController) from another ViewController (ProjectInfosViewController). I end up with an error when I execute the function from the second.

For the context, it is for a navigation button of 3 UIViewController belonging to a UITabBarViewController, itself embedded in a UINavigationController

Thank you in advance ! (Sorry for my bad English)

```
import UIKit

//MARK:-TAB CONTROLLER
class ProjectTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ui_saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // code
        disableSaveButton() // ALL IT'S FINE HERE
    }
    func enableSaveButton() {
        ui_saveButton.title = "Save"
        ui_saveButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    func disableSaveButton() {
        ui_saveButton.title = "Saved"
        ui_saveButton.isEnabled = false
    } }

//MARK:-PROJECT INFORMATIONS

class ProjectInfosViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let superController = ProjectTabBarController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        superController.enableSaveButton() // BUT HERE, DOESN'T
    } }

//MARK:-PROJECT FIXTURES

class ProjectFixturesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
     }

//MARK:-PROJECT CONTACT

class ProjectContactViewController: UIViewController {
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
let superController = ProjectTabBarController()
```

is a new vc that's not presented , if the vc is inside the tabController then do

```
let res = self.tabBarController as! ProjectTabBarController
res.......// call what you need
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understood (I think!)